# How to add wsdl authentication to Jmeter

Tags: soap, jmeter

I have installed `JMeter` for the first time today. I am trying to do a simple `SOAP request`. When i run a method the error:

> "An error occured when verifying security for the message"

shows in the Result tree.

Makes sense. In Soap UI (What i normally use) i have to give the following credentials in the request property:

```
Username: <username>
Password: <password>
Domain: empty
Authentication type: No authorization
WSS-Password Type: "PasswordText"
```

In `SOAPUI` this works. When i execute this method i get my results

So i tried in `JMeter` to add "HTTP Authorization Manager" with:

```
Base URL: Same url as i use in the test request
Username: <username>
Password: <password>
domain: empty
realm: emty
Mechanism: tried both options
```

When i run in again no change. It doesnt seem like `JMeter` even looks are the values in the `HTTP Authorisation manager`. I tried to add it in the root of the Thread group and i tried to make it a child of the request

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Note. I also tried it with the 'Login Config Element'. No change. Still "An error occured when verifying security for the message" in the results :(

Comment: Noone to help me? I have looked everywhere online. JMeter seems to have NO community and NO support

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler instead of [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) as HTTP Request respects HTTP Authorization Manager.

You can use [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in order to set `Content-Type` and `SOAPAction` headers.

See [Take the Pain out of Load Testing Secure Web Services](https://blazemeter.com/blog/take-pain-out-load-testing-secure-web-services) for more details on load testing protected web services.

Also be aware that you can do some load testing using SoapUI itself (however you'll have limited reporting and no clustering capabilities). See [Using SoapUI for load testing](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/load-testing.html) for more information